# SQL: how to find sum of two input parameters with parameters appearing in multiple tables?

Tags: sql

I have financial data where I have following tables and brackets indicating input parameters of respective tables:

1) Stock (Stock_id, Stock_name) 
2) Portfolio (PortfID, Stock_id, Shares)
3) Trans (PortfID, Stock_id)
4) day_list (Stock_id, last_trade)

I need to show PortfID, list of stocks and current value of portfolio. The formula I used for finding current value is sum(Shares*last_trade)

Hence I wrote the following code:

```
SELECT Portfolio.PortfID, Portfolio.Stock_id, Stock.Stock_name,  day_list.last_trade, Portfolio.Shares, Sum(Shares*last_trade)
FROM Portfolio, Stock, day_list
WHERE Portfolio.Stock_id = day_list.Stock_id AND Stock.Stock_id = Portfolio.Stock_id
GROUP BY PortfID
```

I get an error saying "You tried to execute a query that does not include specified expression 'Stock_id' as part of an aggregate function"

Can anyone make any corrections please?

Comment: all values in the SELECT part of the query must appear in the GROUP BY part unless they are under an aggregate function (E.g. SUM/ MIN/ MAX/..)

Comment: wow that was superb, it worked...how do I get one value for each portfolio though?

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by all the columns not participating in the aggregated function.  You should also qualify columns Shares and last_Trade.

```
SELECT p.PortfID, p.Stock_id, s.Stock_name, d.last_trade, p.Shares, Sum(Shares * last_trade)
FROM Portfolio p, Stock s, day_list d
WHERE p.Stock_id = d.Stock_id 
AND s.Stock_id =  p.Stock_id
GROUP BY p.PortfID, p.Stock_id, s.Stock_name, d.last_trade, p.Shares
```

If you want a sum by portfolio, then remove Stock_id, Stock_name, last_Trade and Shares from the SELECT and GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Error: Too Few parameters. Expected 1.